# Is there any way to change TextView font type by adding in settings?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is there any way to add an item to settings that changes TextView font type  ? (for ex TimesNewRoman to Calibri etc )

Comment: Are you asking about Cocoa, or Cocoa Touch?

Comment: I ask what kind of item I will add into settings.bundle in XCode in order to change font type of text in a TextView. Then yes cocoa I think

Comment: Settings.bundle? That's Cocoa Touch, unless you're confused about how to implement preferences in a Mac app.

Answer (score 0):

In settings there is no way, maybe some new XCode version, but in code is very easy, you can do:

```
[myTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:14]];
```

Also http://iosfonts.com/ can help you a lot, with font names and iOs versions available.